# How to make BootStrap-DatePicker Stop Submit Form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a problem with bootstrap datepicker.
I have tried hard for having a solution, but unfortunately I am not able to find a solution.

**Problem description**
Bootstrap Datepicker is making calls to Web Application server unnecessary. Or may be i can say it as without asking it to do so.

**My Form**

```
<form class="fill" action="<% testbeanHandle.dummy(); %>"  id="inputForm">
<label class="control-label" >Date:</label>
<input value="2015-01-14" type="text" name="pickedDate" style="width: 160px;" id="datepicker"/>
</form>
```

**My Library**

- css/bootstrap.min.css
- js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js
- js/bootstrap.min.js
- css/bootstrap-datepicker.css
- js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

**My JavaScript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //AJAX to call the Web Server, when it detects any change in form.
 $('#inputForm').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var post_data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: post_data,
      success: function() {
      }
    });
  });

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        clearBtn: true,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        orientation: "top left"
       });

});
```

**My Server Side Bean**

```
@Named("testbean")
@SessionScoped 
public class testBean implements testapi,Serializable {
    @Override    
    public void dummy() {
             Date dNow = new Date();
             SimpleDateFormat ft =  
             new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a zzz");
             System.out.println(ft.format(dNow)+": "
                    +"See I am called..");
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The Phrase "See I am called.." was expected to be printed in the Web Server console only once, that too each time the Date is changed.

But the Phrase "See I am called.." had been printed three time each and when ever the date is changed. 
That means, changing the Date is making call to web server twice.

```
Info:   2015-04-26 01:49:22 PM CEST: See I am called..
Info:   2015-04-26 01:49:23 PM CEST: See I am called..
Info:   2015-04-26 01:49:23 PM CEST: See I am called..
```

Note: I tried to remove the BootStrap Datepicker and had the date field as a simple text field. After that the problem disappears. 
But problem is only when I use Bootstrap Datepicker Plugin.

May I know how to fix this issue 
Thanks

Comment: not sure but maybe the bootstrap is hiding plain input box and creating datepicker on top of it and whenever the datepicker is changed the value of that plain input is also changing causing two change events to trigger, why not call ajax on datepicker change itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a Lot for all your reply.

**First**

Infact I am not comfortable in using ajax call within datepicker change event itself. Because the Form that I handle does not only have DatePicker it should have other Input fields also. 
So I am ruling out that method

**Second**
Catching the previous send data is obviously another option 
send_data = post_data;
Which works for me

**Third**

However I have found out the issue and a way to fix it without a workaround.

I made the following changes in the 
Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.4.0 ( bootstrap-datepicker.js )

Under **setValue** Function call

I could see a statement

```
this.element.find('input').val(formatted).change();
```

This is triggered when the Datepicker Show the calendar view and hide the calendar view.

Hence it make call to web-platform. 
Because I guess it is tracking the input change event of the Input Text Field. Over which the Date-picker sits. ( Not Sure though )

So I managed to change that to

```
this.element.find('input').val(formatted).change(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

In the Library, and I see that my issue got fixedc.

Thanks you very much. And I hope these help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remember the last send data and dont send them if they are identical and nothing has changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var send_data='';
$('#inputForm').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var post_data = form.serialize();
  if (post_data !== send_data ) {
    send_data = post_data;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: post_data,
      success: function() {
      }
    });
   }
  });
....
```

HTH
Georg